# Entity Framework Core OnModelCreating vs Migration, the correct development workflow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

can you please explain to me the difference between having the following:

- Decorate a class with EF Core attribute such as **DataAnnotations** VS using the code inside **OnModelCreating** to define relationships and mapping?
- Creating a Migration class using dotnet ef migrations add "xyz" VS configuring it into **OnModelCreating**?

I am trying to make a sort of "Development workflow" but the docs are not really clear about it.

I found that I should:

1. Create your first "Database Context"
2. Create a set of classes representing my Model
3. Override **OnModelCreating** to specify the mapping strategies for each Model object
4. Execute `add migrations` and `ef update` as many times as I change something

Is this the correct flow to work with Entity Framework Core?

Comment: `dotnet migrations add MigrationName` and when you want to apply migration to database `dotnet ef database update`

Comment: @J.Doe this is clear but what is the correct working flow to use EF Core and when I should use OnModelCreating instead of the Migration class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Decorate a class with EF Core attribute such as DataAnnotations VS
>   using the code inside OnModelCreating to define relationships and
>   mapping?

Data Annotations are 'inline', but you mix entities with persistence logic. It's the sweet spot, in my opinion. `OnModelCreating` enables you to use the 'Fluent API', which is more powerful and flexible, but/and detaches the persistence logic somewhat from your entities. Sometimes you use a mix of both - data annotations and Fluent API.

> Creating a Migration class using dotnet ef migrations add "xyz" VS
>   configuring it into OnModelCreating?

Not sure I understand this. I don't see an alternative to migrations.

The way I work with EF (code-first) is:

1. I write my entities and add data annotations to them
2. I generate a migration and get SQL script from it, then delete the migration code
3. Execute the .SQL against the database
4. Run the code
5. Entity changes
6. Generate new migration .SQL and store it as part of the project

Basically a 'migration' is necessary when you want to update the database to be compatible with your new/changed code.

`OnModelCreating` is necessary when you have to tell EF how the entities map to a database. You shouldn't confuse the two things.

Comment: Actually this is the answer I needed to better understand how it works because before I was using a Class per Model for mapping, now it goes all into OnModelCreating

Comment: The thing is that the very first time you run your code, it will create your db tables without a migration.